# Is there an Android Studio Shortcut to add Widgets/EditText/etc like TextView/Buttons?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.2, android-studio-2.1

I try to avoid using my mouse as much as possible, so I'm always looking forward to learn all the available hotkeys/shortcuts.

**My current question/problem:**
I'm trying to visually add stuff from the Android Studio Palette, such as Widgets (TextView, Button), Text Fields (EditText) without using my mouse.

Is there any way to open a search box like <kbd>CTRL + SHIFT + A</kbd>  or <kbd>Shift + Shift</kbd> so I can quickly type something like "textview" and  then drag it to my UI?

Or do I have to manually go to the "Pallete", find the element I want and then drag them every single time? I'd love to be able to add those elements to my UI without having to go there with my mouse and drag and drop.

I have checked:
https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/keyboard-shortcuts.html
But sadly no luck into finding what I need.

Thank you in advance for your time.
I'm not a native english speaker, I'm really sorry if I haven't made myself perfectly clear.

**TL;DR:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/zYmtt.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tap on the "Pallete" and type the element name you want then the "Pallet" will auto-scrolled to the element location and you can then drag and drop the required element to the UI

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was looking for some better way though, I believe it's just not avaliable sadly.

Comment: Yes i think this is the only method.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps its `Alt+Enter` you are looking for. It lets you wrap the existing code with certain common widgets!